# Latest Jersey example does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, http, jersey

I have isntalled the latest version of jersey (Bundle-Version: 2.13.0) and the examples for that version. Then I tried (for testing Restful services - \examples\helloworld-pure-jax-rs\src\main\java\org\glassfish\jersey\examples) the Hello World example in Eclipse. The result ist this:

```
"Hello World" Jersey Example Application
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No container provider supports the type interface com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:87)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.createEndpoint(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:71)
at org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.jaxrs.App.startServer(App.java:72)
at org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.jaxrs.App.main(App.java:88)
```

I thought the example should work out of the box as it does not use any specific http servers. Only

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
```

My Java version is:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any idea what could be wrong or what I missed?

best
Klemens

Comment: If you are missing the `target` folder, you should build your project first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Maven and with Eclipse

First I tried with Maven from command line ([you need Maven installed](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)). It worked fine.

Steps:

1. Downloaded [Jersey 2.13 Examples bundle](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jersey-examples/2.13/jersey-examples-2.13-all.zip) from [here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html)
2. Unzipped to `${myJerseyExampleLocation}` (whatever the location may be)
3. `cd ${myJerseyExampleLocation}/jersey/examples/helloworld-pure-jax-rs`
4. `mvn package` - This downloaded all the dependencies and ran one unit test `HelloWorldTest` successfully
5. To run the main app `mvn exec:java`. This runs the `App` class through the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) listed in the `<plugins>` section of the pom. Result:

   ```
   Application started.
   Try accessing http://localhost:8080/helloworld in the browser.
   Hit enter to stop the application...
   ```
6. From browser to to `http://localhost:8080/helloworld`. Result is `Hello World!`
7. Go back to command line and hit enter to stop server

From Eclipse:

I first delete the entire unzipped example, as it was already built. I wanted to do it from scratch from Eclipse.

Steps:

1. Unzipped
2. From Eclipse `Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects` Browse for `helloworld-pure-jax-rs` and select select it `Finish`
3. Right click on project `Run As -> Maven Build`. In the dialog in the `goals` field type `package` The `Apply -> Run`. This will grab all the dependencies. You should get a `Build Successful` along with a successful unit test.
4. Two options to run:

   - Open the `App` class, right click it and `Run as -> Java Application`. You should get the same result in the Eclipse console as mention the Maven Step 5.
   - Right click on project, select `Run as -> Maven Build` (there are two select the one you haven't selected yet from the previous step). You will get the dialog again. This allows you to configure a different run configuration. In the `goals` type `exec:java`. Then run. You should get same result as above.

In Eclipse environment, tested with 1.7.0_65 and 1.8.0_20

Hopefully you can get it to work. Let me know what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked now. I installed the latest Eclipse version and followed your steps.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was following an example. Finally I only needed to add this dependency `org.glassfish.jersey.containers` **`jersey-container-jdk-http`** (remember the exception's message "No *container* provider supports the type interface com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler"):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

You could change the version according your environment.