# I cannot publish a simple JAX-RS service using TomEE and Eclipse (IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs, cxf

The problem seems to be some poor error message.

I've created a dynamic web app project in eclipse and the runtime is TomEE+ 1.7.2

So this is the publisher

```
package study;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class StandaloneJaxRsServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(
                "localhost", 8765), 8);
        HttpHandler requestHandler = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance()
                .createEndpoint(new JaxRSApplication(), HttpHandler.class); //<<<<< line 15
        server.createContext("/jaxrs/", requestHandler);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

this is the app

```
package study;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath(value="/jaxrs")
public class JaxRSApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(NotSingletonResource.class);
        return set ;
    }
//
//  @Override
//  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
//      Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
//      set.add(new SingletonResource());
//      return set ;
//  }

}
```

and this is the resource

```
package study;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/notSingletonResource")
public class NotSingletonResource {

    private volatile int counter = 0;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
    public String getHello() {
        return "Not singleton resource " + counter++;
    }

}
```

when I try to run StandaloneJaxRsServer.main() I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl.createEndpoint(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:104)
    at study.StandaloneJaxRsServer.main(StandaloneJaxRsServer.java:15)
```

However, IllegalArgumentException does not tell much. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for the `RuntimeDelegate` interface states "Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if application is null or the requested endpoint type is not supported.'  For a JAX-RS Application, I think you're supposed to use `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean`, and use the result of creating the endpoint to set up a server.

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept my own answer, I just want to keep here some useful information just in case someone needs it.

TomEE+ does not have the libraries to make this work. Instead, what I've did was to remove all the TomEE+ dependencies from my eclipse project, then I've converted it to a maven project just to include [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-jdk-http) according to @lmiguelmh answer to this question:

[Latest Jersey example does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542268/latest-jersey-example-does-not-work)

Then I've just added these jersey libraries

[image]

I'll wait a little bit more before accepting an answer here, because I really would like a better answer. I am following the steps described in the book "Java Web Services, Up and Running", so I think people will really need to know this information.